# Run a code in 'n' different machines but execute only once

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to run a python code in windows. The code should always be running that is 24*7.

In order to make the code running, i want to run it on 5 different machines. So that if machine 1 does then code will be run by machine 2 and if machine 2 dies then the code will be run by machine 3 and so on.

I tried searching on internet but didnt find any solution.

Is there any way to run a python program 24*7 only one time but using 5 machines?

Any help Or any link to solve this issue will be of great help.

Comment: Python itself can not provide [failover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failover) for you, and such topic is better discussed on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) anyway.

Comment: Considering that you're a newbie, I strongly advise to just run your code in the cloud, where uptime is pretty much guaranteed. Implementing your own solution is an advanced topic. For recommend [pythonanyhwere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) which is very straight forward to use (used it myself for quite some time)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I dont want to use cloud. Is there any other solution?